# Dojango and Dojox plugins

Tags: django, dojo

Basically, I would like to use the **dojox/editor/plugins/UploadImage** in my **dojango** loaded editor. The plan is not to have a file browser just to upload an image and insert it into a text area.

Currently I have the **Dojango 0.5.4** installed and its loading **dojo 1.7.0.**

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is half the truth;

Extending a plugin:

```
var myUploadImage = dojo.declare("__UploadImage", [dojox.editor.plugins.UploadImage], {

    // extension point

});
```

Hooking onto plugin loader

```
dojo.subscribe(dijit._scopeName + ".Editor.getPlugin",null,function(o){
  var name = o.args.name.toLowerCase();
  if(name === "__uploadImage"){
      o.plugin = new myUploadImage({
        url: ("url" in o.args)?o.args.url:"",
        logResults: ("logResults" in o.args)?o.args.logResults:true
        ....
       });
  }
});
```

Instantiating editor

```
new dijit.Editor({
  plugins: [
    '__uploadImage',  // note name change to avoid namespace collapses
    ...
// or
    { name: '__uploadImage', url: 'path/to/upload', ... },
    ...
  ]
});
```